# ¿Cómo crear una tabla en SQL Server sin necesidad de darle nombre a las columnas?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla en SQL Server que tiene dos campos (id,Xml) en la columna xml se guardan datos como estos:

```
<Sheet1>
<Production_x0020_Line>L1B4</Production_x0020_Line>
<Item_x0020_Number>VPJG7F-10849-BD</Item_x0020_Number>
<Fecha>02/20 - 02/26</Fecha>
<cantidad>2</cantidad>
</Sheet1>
<Sheet1>
<Production_x0020_Line>L1B4</Production_x0020_Line>
<Item_x0020_Number>VPJG7F-10849-DD</Item_x0020_Number>
<Fecha>02/20 - 02/26</Fecha>
<cantidad>1</cantidad>
</Sheet1>
```

Con este código esos datos Xml los puedo ver en una tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE TablaXML ( Id INT, ContenidoXML XML)

INSERT INTO TablaXML (Id, ContenidoXML) VALUES (1, '<Sheet1>      <Production_x0020_Line>L1B4</Production_x0020_Line><Item_x0020_Number>VPJG7F-10849-BD</Item_x0020_Number><Fecha>02/20 - 02/26</Fecha><cantidad>2</cantidad></Sheet1><Sheet1><Production_x0020_Line>L1B4</Production_x0020_Line><Item_x0020_Number>VPJG7F-10849-DD</Item_x0020_Number><Fecha>02/20 - 02/26</Fecha><cantidad>1</cantidad></Sheet1>')

SELECT * FROM TablaXML

DECLARE @xml XML

SELECT @xml = ContenidoXML FROM TablaXML

SELECT  
   Tabla.Columna.value('Production_x0020_Line[1]', 'VARCHAR(64)') AS   'Production line',
   Tabla.Columna.value('Item_x0020_Number[1]', 'VARCHAR(64)') AS 'Item Number',
   Tabla.Columna.value('Fecha[1]', 'VARCHAR(64)') AS 'Date',
   Tabla.Columna.value('cantidad[1]', 'smallint') AS 'Quantity' 
   FROM   @xml.nodes('//Sheet1') Tabla(Columna)
```

¿Cómo le hago para poder ver otros datos en una tabla sin la necesidad de poner todos los nombres de columnas?

Porque en este código son pocas columnas, ¿Qué tal si los siguientes datos contienen más de 100 columnas?

Answer (score 2):

Si haces uso del tipo de columna [xml type](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-data-type-and-columns-sql-server):

[Querying XML fields using t-sql](http://www.brokenwire.net/bw/Programming/125/querying-xml-fields-using-t-sql)

[How can I query a value in SQL Server XML column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344553/how-can-i-query-a-value-in-sql-server-xml-column)

Verás que puedes consultarlo directamente:

```
select ContenidoXML.query('/Sheet1/Production_x0020_Line') from TablaXML
```

La idea es usar:

- [query() Method (xml Data Type)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/query-method-xml-data-type)
- [value() Method (xml Data Type)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type)

Comment: El *query* `select ContenidoXML.query('/Sheet1/Production_x0020_Line') from TablaXML` solo traerá la columna con el contenido XML, si la idea es usar  `value` como mencionas, se tienen que especificar explícitamente las columnas así como lo pregunta el usuario, y que es lo que no quiere

Answer (score 2):

La única forma que veo por ahora es recuperar los nombres de los campos y usarlos para armar una consulta dinámica, algo así:

```
DECLARE @xml XML
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)

SELECT  @xml = ContenidoXML FROM TablaXML
SELECT  @SQL = 'select '+ STUFF((SELECT distinct     ',T.X.value(''('+C.Name+'/text())[1]'', ''nvarchar(max)'') as ' + C.Name from     @xml.nodes('Sheet1/*') as T(X) 
                            cross apply (select T.X.value('local-name(.)',     'nvarchar(max)')) as C(Name)
                            for xml path(''), type).value('text()[1]',     'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')+
                ' from @x.nodes(''Sheet1'') as T(X)'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@x xml', @xml
```

Para más detalle ver [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25640784/how-to-select-all-column-in-xml)

Comment: Ya hago esa consulta dinamica, crees que ese codigo lo pueda colocar en mi codigo de c# , es una aplicacion de escritorio.

Comment: No veo porque no, lo único es que hay que ser consciente que el uso de nvarchar(MAX)  para escribir la consulta dinámica tiene un límite en el tamaño, bastante grande (creo que son 2 Gbytes), pero un límite al fin.

Comment: @abi logré probar la ejecución de este código y sin duda funciona, muy buen aporte. Solo sería cuestión que lo ajustes a tus necesidades.

Comment: @Flxtr, si a mi tambien me funciona, pero si quiero hacer eso para mas de 1000 datos, crees que se pueda?

Comment: @abi claro, hice la prueba agregando más datos al XML y me funcionó bastante bien :)

Comment: @Flxtr, si lose, pero mi Jefe no quiere hacer nada de eso, quiere que con un codigo se haga todo, osea los datos que tengo nunca son los mismos, cambian por dia, por esa razon no puedo poner un codigo fijo, osea al codigo siempre tendria que agregarle mas y el no quiere eso, no se si lo que quiere el tenga alguna solucion ;v

Comment: @abi hagamos lo siguiente, edita tu pregunta y pon otro XML un poco más completo, que tenga más datos, esto para simular tu caso, porque según lo que entiendo, tu consulta deberá funcionar para N número de elementos del XML, ¿correcto? Bueno, añade otro ejemplo para darnos una idea del problema que presentas :)

Comment: El uso de sentencias dinámicas cuando se definen como nvarchar(MAX) tiene un limite de unos 2 Gbytes, que significa? en el caso de este ejemplo, lo que hace crecer la consulta es la cantidad de campos y la longitud del nombre de cada uno, podemos más o menos hacer una estimación: supongamos que en promedio cada nombre de campo tiene 20 caracteres, si no me falla la cuenta, esto nos daría un máximo de 100.000 campos, tal vez un poco menos por el resto de las sentencias de la consulta. Es un número bastante amplio, pero bueno sigue siendo un límite.

Answer (score -1):

select ContenidoXML.query('/Sheet1/Production_x0020_Line') from TablaXML

revisa la correcta instalacion de sql , te comparto un manual de comoinstalar SQL Server.

Comment: Esta respeusta es exactamente igual a otra dada. Que quisiste hacer? por favor mira [answer]

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).